# basic join on mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am having a hard time understanding joins on mySQL, and I cannot find any similar example to work with.

Suppose I have two tables: `users` and `users_info`.

in users I have `id`, `email` and `password` fields while, in `users_info` I have all their information, like `name`, `surname`, `street`, etc.

so, if I am getting a user like this:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = 43
```

and their information like this:

```
SELECT * FROM users_info WHERE id = 43
```

I will basically get 2 results, and 2 tables.

I understand now that I need to use join so that they are all together, but I just can't figure out out.

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

It seems like both tables `users` and `user_info` are related with each others by the column `id` therefore you need to join them using this column like this:

```
SELECT 
  u.id,
  u.email,
  u.password,
  i.name, 
  i.surname, 
  i.street
FROM users           AS u
INNER JOIN user_info AS i ON u.id = i.id;
```

This will only select the fields `id, email, ... etc`. **However**, if you want to select all the columns from both the tables use `SELECT *`:

```
SELECT *
FROM users           AS u
INNER JOIN user_info AS i ON u.id = i.id;
```

If you want to input the `id` and get all of these data for a specific user, add a `WHERE` clause at the end of the query:

```
SELECT *
FROM users           AS u
INNER JOIN user_info AS i ON u.id = i.id
WHERE u.id = 43;
```

---

For more information about `JOIN` kindly see the following:

- [**Join (SQL)<sup>From Wikipedia</sup>**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29).
- [**Visual Representation of SQL Joins**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins).
- [**Another Visual Explanation of SQL Joins**](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can also do:

```
SELECT users.*, users_info.*
FROM users, users_info
WHERE users.id = users_info.id AND users.id = 43;
```

This means:
"Get me all the columns from the users table, all the columns from the users_info table for the lines where the id column of users and the id column of users_info correspond to each other"

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example

```
SELECT * FROM users u
INNER JOIN users_info i
ON u.id=i.id
```

this means, you are joining users table and users_info table

for example

users

```
id     name
----   -------
 1      abc
 2      xyz
```

users_info

```
id     email 
---    ------
 1      abc@aaa.com
 2      xyz@aaa.com
```

the query will return

```
id    name   email
---   -----  -------
 1     abc    abc@aaa.com
 2     xyz    xyz@aaa.com
```

[Here's a nice tutorial](http://phpweby.com/tutorials/mysql/32)